# Margin on PDF page exported by Kendo

Tags: javascript, pdf, kendo-ui

I try to set margin for PDF page exported by Kendo UI ,

I used [drawDOM](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/drawing#methods-drawDOM) and set the options object as this -

```
{
    options: {
        margin: {
            bottom: 50
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't get any margin in the PDF .

[**HERE IS A DEMO**](http://dojo.telerik.com/@urielz/ElUVa/4)

How to get it work ?

Comment: You probably need to show some more code here, like a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mvce) that explains how you're reading those options in, and what code around it might interfere (which is why you should create an mvce, because in the process of removing all the bits that don't relate to your problem, you might actually solve the issue, and now have better information to guide you in writing your code)

Comment: I would like to give more details , but this  is the excatly code needed  here , those how works with Kendo would understand it immediatly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the options object on the exportPDF call.

It should be something like `return draw.exportPDF(root, {margin: {bottom: "50"}});`

Take a look at the reference for [PDFOptions](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/drawing/pdfoptions) for what can be applied in that second parameter.

Comment: I try it but I don't get any margin , can you suuply a demo please ? 
you can fork my demo in my post .

Comment: @URL87 [This example](http://dojo.telerik.com/EFAxA/2) is working for me, at least as I understand what you're asking for.